# Plot simple moving average over dataframe in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe, julia-plots

I have an excel file with dates and stock prices. I read this data into a dataframe with DataFrames.jl

```
using DataFrames, StatsPlots, Indicators

df = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("Demo-sv.xlsx", "Blad3")...)
```

This works great and here I print the first 6 entries.

```
6×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ Date       │ Closeprice │
│     │ Any        │ Any        │
├─────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ 2019-05-03 │ 169.96     │
│ 2   │ 2019-05-02 │ 168.06     │
│ 3   │ 2019-04-30 │ 165.58     │
│ 4   │ 2019-04-29 │ 166.4      │
│ 5   │ 2019-04-26 │ 167.76     │
│ 6   │ 2019-04-25 │ 167.46     │
```

I then plot this data with StatsPlots.jl `@df df plot(df.Date, df.Closeprice)` and get a nice plot graph.

The problem is when I want to plot a simple moving average with Indicators.jl

```
movingaverage = sma(df, n=200)
plot!(movingaverage, linewidth=2, color=:red)
```

I get this error message

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching sma(::DataFrame; n=200)
Closest candidates are:
sma(::Array{T,N} where N; n) where T<:Real at 
/Users/HBrovell/.julia/packages/Indicators/QGmEX/src/ma.jl:8
sma(::Temporal.TS{V,T}; args...) where {V, T} at 
/Users/HBrovell/.julia/packages/Indicators/QGmEX/src/temporal.jl:64
```

What I understand, I need to convert the DataFrame so I will be able to use the Indicators.jl sma function. I have tried with `convert(Array{Float64}, df[2])` to only convert the Closeprice column, but that didn't work the way I wanted. I guess I don't want to convert the date column?

So how can I convert the DataFrame, so I can use the sma function in Indicators.jl, or is there a better way than using DataFrames.jl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume what you need is:

```
sma(sort(df, :Date).ClosePrice, n=200)
```

One additional problem you have is the data type of your `ClosePrice` column that should be numeric rather than `Any`

You need to convert it somehow, for an example:

```
df[!, :ClosePrice] .= Float64.(df.ClosePrice)
```

Comment: I seem to get the same error message if I do this, which I assume you mean.

    ```df = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("Demo-sv.xlsx", "Blad3")...)```
    ```@df df plot(df.Date, df.Closeprice)```
    ```movingaverage = sma(sort(df, :Date).Closeprice, n=200)```
    ```plot!(movingaverage, linewidth=2, color=:red)```

Comment: Or correction I now get the following error message, where the "no method matching" is now Array instead of DataFrame.

ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching sma(::Array{Any,1}; n=200)
Closest candidates are:
  sma(::Array{T,N} where N; n) where T<:Real at /Users/HBrovell/.julia/packages/Indicators/QGmEX/src/ma.jl:8
  sma(::Temporal.TS{V,T}; args...) where {V, T} at /Users/HBrovell/.julia/packages/Indicators/QGmEX/src/temporal.jl:64

Comment: yeah you have one additional issue in the data - I edited the answer.

Comment: That works, now I don't get any error messages. But my dates get very wrong in the plot graph. I get dates like -0059-01-01 and 0476-01-01. Do I also need to convert that from any, to a date format?

Comment: This depends on how you are parsing and formatting the dates. If you have problem with that I recommend asking a separate question.